# Solution to $y^{\prime \prime} -xy = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation of the form

$y^{\prime \prime} - xy = 0$,

which I'm told has a solution of the form

$y(x) = p(x) e^{-q(x)}$.

I've been trying to solve for q(x) by differentiating y(x) and plugging it into the ODE directly, which led me to find

$p^{\prime \prime}(x) - 2p^{\prime}(x)q^{\prime}(x) + p(x)(q^{\prime}(x)^2 - q^{\prime \prime}(x)) = xp(x)$,

but I'm not sure where to go from here, or if this is even the right direction. I've been given a hint that to solve for $q(x)$, I'll need to think about the behaviour of $p(x)$ for large $x$. Since $p(x)$ looks like an amplitude to an oscillation, I feel like it will go to $0$ over time.

I would appreciate any help on how to to get a solution of this form.

EDIT: for large enough $x$, I think we can make the approximation that $y^{\prime \prime}(x) << y^{\prime}(x)^2$, although I'm not sure yet exactly how this could help.

Comment: $\int \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} dx=\frac{dy}{dx}$, the equation is separable, you are overthinking here by introducing $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ unneccessarily

Comment: I think you misread the equation. This is the Airy Eq. which is not separable like you suggested. My problem is that I am looking for a solution not in terms of the Airy functions, but in a different form (the one I stated in my question)

Comment: Probably won't help much, but the right-hand side should have only $xp(x)$ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have $2$ functions parametrizing one solution. Thus you can add one external condition on the relation of $p$ and $q$. One relatively natural condition is that the "amplitude" $p$ varies much more slowly than the "phase" $q$, meaning that the derivatives of $p$ are dominated by the derivatives of $q$. This then suggests to extract from the dominant terms
$$
q'(x)^2=x
$$
so that the remaining equation is
$$
p''(x)-2p'(x)q'(x)-p(x)q''(x)=0
$$
Here again one can concentrate in a first approximation on the dominant terms
$$
-2p'(x)q'(x)-p(x)q''(x)=0\implies p(x)^2q'(x)=C
$$
In total this gives the first order of the WKB approximation method.

Answer (score 0):

This ODE is well known it is called  Airy equation whoose two linearly independent solutions are $Ai(x)$ and $Bi(x)$ So the most general solution is
$$y(x)= C_1 Ai(x)+ C_2 Bi (x).$$

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function

Answer (score -1):

Well, if all you want to do is solve for $q(x),$ then that's just the logarithm of $p(x)/y(x).$ That is, if you rewrite your equation as $$\frac{y(x)}{p(x)}=e^{-q(x)},$$ whence, by raising both sides to the power $-1$ we get  $$\frac{p(x)}{y(x)}=e^{q(x)},$$ from which it follows that $$q(x)=\log\left(\frac{p(x)}{y(x)}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this doesn't really address the question. Specifically, I am looking for a way to write the solution of y in the form I mentioned. q(x) will come naturally from the solution.

Comment: @jrobinson What you want is not clear. Do you want to see how to solve the differential equation or how to rearrange the solution? I took the latter because of the place where you explained, *I've been trying to solve for $q(x)$...*

Comment: I am looking for a solution to the differential equation, y(x), that is in the form y(x)=p(x) exp(-q(x)). By solving for q(x), I mean finding the solution y(x) in this form and taking q(x) from it.

Comment: @jrobinson What do you mean by *taking $q(x)$ from it*? Do you mean to express $q(x)$ in terms of the other expressions in the solution?